# React native - how to check sound output

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

i wanna to detect the output of sound in react native project.
Will the sound be played from the headphones or in built-in speakers?
how can i check this?
Does it need a special permstions?like bluetooth for wierless headphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use **react-native-device-info**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info

it have a method **isHeadphonesConnected()**

Tells if the device is connected to wired headset or bluetooth headphones

```
  DeviceInfo.isHeadphonesConnected().then((enabled) => {
  if(enabled){
     // implementation for the case when headphone is connected
}else{
    //implementation for the case when headphone is not connected
});
```

and it also contain a hook through which you can check whether wired headset or bluetooth headphones are connected

**useIsHeadphonesConnected**

Tells if the device is connected to wired headset or bluetooth headphones.

This hook subscribes to the event, RNDeviceInfo_headphoneConnectionDidChange , and updates the result field accordingly
example

```
 import { useIsHeadphonesConnected } from 'react-native-device-info';

const { loading, result } = useIsHeadphonesConnected(); // { loading: true, result: false}

<Text>{loading ? 'loading...' : result}</Text>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#isHeadphonesConnected

```js
// Tells if the device is connected to wired headset or bluetooth headphones
DeviceInfo.isHeadphonesConnected().then((enabled) => {
  // true or false
});
```